# not able to access pageobjects outside the class in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android, page-factory

Hello I am not an expert but have some idea about selenium, I have written the class page and created the object also, but still not able to access the elements from object class
not sure what is wrong.

```
public class AllBotsPage extends Baseclass {


public AllBotsPage(WebDriver wd){
    PageFactory.initElements(wd,this);
}

    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using  = "//*[@id='bui-8__anchor']")
    public static WebElement messageIcon;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@aria-checked][1]")
    WebElement agentOnlineIcon;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//button[contains(text(),'New')]")
    public static WebElement newTab;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//button[contains(text(),'Start Conversation')]")
    public WebElement startConversationButton;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@placeholder='Search users...']")
    public WebElement searchUser;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[name()='circle' and @cx='14.4']")
    public WebElement resolveChatOptions;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[text()='Resolve conversation']")
    public WebElement resolveConversation;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@type='button' and contains(text(),'Confirm')]")
    public WebElement confirmResolveChat;


    public void selectBot( String name){

        String a = "//*[@class='botcard__namewrapper' and //span[contains(text(),'"+name+"')]]";
        /*WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(wd,Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(a))).click();*/
        wd.findElement(By.xpath(a)).click();

    }

    public boolean verifyMessage(String value){

        if (wd.findElement(By.xpath("//span[normalize-space()='"+value+"'])[2]")).getText().contains(value));
        return true;
    }

    public void setAgentOnline(boolean value){
        if (agentOnlineIcon.isEnabled() == false){
            agentOnlineIcon.click();
        }
    }



}
```

Trying to access these objects in below class

```
public class Whatsapp extends Baseclass {

    @Test
    public void Whtsapp() {

        WhatsAppPage whtsapp = new WhatsAppPage(md);
        AllBotsPage albot = new AllBotsPage(wd);


        wLogin("Auto@test.com","Rak@1234");

        albot.selectBot("Autobot");
        albot.messageIcon.click();

        albot.setAgentOnline(true);

        System.out.println("sending a message from whatsapp");
        startApp("whtsapp");
        whtsapp.searchButton.click();
        whtsapp.searcTextbox.sendKeys("D360 26");
        whtsapp.searchResult.click();
        whtsapp.sendTextmsg.sendKeys("Hello Appium");
        whtsapp.sendButton.click();

        albot.newTab.click();
        albot.searchUser.sendKeys("9535143660");
        albot.startConversationButton.click();
        albot.verifyMessage("Hello Appium");
        albot.resolveChatOptions.click();
        albot.resolveConversation.click();
        albot.confirmResolveChat.click();

     }
}
```

I get null pointer error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Pages.WebPages.AllBotsPage.selectBot(AllBotsPage.java:53)
    at Tests.Whatsapp.Whtsapp(Whatsapp.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:766)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You pasted your code without the imports and it is hard to tell which is the exact line where you get the failure.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, i resolved, I had to create methods within the class using those objects, only then i was able to access it. I was not able to access it just by creating a page object.